# Accessing PCA components from caret object in R

Tags: r, pca, caret

I know how to build a model using PCA components in caret package, however I don't know which variables explain which PCA components. I need some help on it.

When I perfom the preProcessing separately, like this:

```
trans<-preProcess(training_cl,method="pca",preProcOptions = list(thresh = 0.8))
```

I can check the PCA components of the data, like this:

```
trans$rotation
```

However, when a perfome the PCA components using the caret package:

1. I don't know which variables explain which PCA components(don't know how to access the $rotation).
2. I don't get the same amount of PCA variables when compared with the code above(even when I define the same threshold).

example code using the caret:

```
fitControl <- trainControl(method = "cv",
                       number = 3,
                       preProcOptions = list(thresh = 0.80,pcaComp = NULL))
gbmGrid <-  expand.grid(interaction.depth = seq(3,5,10),
                    n.trees =  seq(100,130,10) ,
                    shrinkage = c(0.1),
                    n.minobsinnode=10
                    )


gbmFit <- train(classe ~ .,method="gbm",
                data=training_cl,
                trControl=fitControl,
                metric="Accuracy",
                tuneGrid = gbmGrid,
                preProc="pca",
                 verbose = FALSE
                )
```

How can I know which variables explain which PCA components when I use the caret package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the "rotation" part can be accessed via:

```
gbmFit$preProcess$rotation
```

The reason is because `gbmFit$preProcess` is a "preProcess" object just as `trans` is. Hence, you can access the "rotation" the same way.

As far as the discrepancy goes, I think it may be because it looks like you're passing in the whole **training_cl** data frame into the preProcess function and not *excluding* the **classe** column. Do you think that could be the problem?

Comment: Thank you!  

I forgot to exclude the classe from my data, I guess that this is why the differance happened.

Now I wonder what will happening if I perfom the gbm with PCA in a data with  NA. I know that gbm can handling with NA, however I don't know  if PCA can handle this situation.


My data has 72  features(observations), but 3 of them has missing values ( by definition some cases don't has values). I don't know if I can define a threshold  in preProcOptions that don't apply pca to that 3 features.